# Solution to read data from NeXT/Apple typedstream data, little endian, version 4, system 1000

Tags: java, macos, deserialization, foundation, openstep

An application that I am currently working on contains several files of the above mentioned type. These files are created using NSArchiver from an legacy framework called OpenStep.

If I am correct than this is a data format which was used pre and begin OS/X and is now replaced by NSKeyedArchiver. Although I think current OS/X implementations of NSUnArchiver can still read this older format.

When opening these files there are some contents which can be read by humans like dataformats such as BlockArray, NSObject etc. The rest is binary data which does not make sense.

I have to be able to retrieve information from these files to process further in a Java based application. I would love to know what you would advise me to do in this case so that I am able to use the information in these files.

A side note:

- The GNUSTEP implementation does not support this typedstream data.
- My main application is written in Java.
- Preferably a solution which does not require me to develop on the OS/X platform.
- Solution should run on Windows platform.